Formula to automatically run operation based on cell names on excel
I'm trying to have a budget table and see what credit cards are the best for my spending.
I have a category section, and a percentage section based on each card`s cash back. I want to automate column E so that I can multiply column D and B based on category name instead of going one by one.
Example for cell E2 should multiply 5% * B8 only if Column D and A match with the name (Gas). How can solve this?




Category
Total
Category
Freedom
Total Rewards
Freedom Unlimited
Total Rewards




Netflix
$ 17.00
Gas
5%

0%



Spotify
$ 12.00
Movie Theaters
5%

0%



Phone
$120.00
Restaurants/Dining
0%

3%



Amazon
$300.00
Drugstores
0%

3%



Fine Fare
$120.00
Lyft Rides
0%

4%



Costco
$200.00
Chase Travel
0%

5%



Gas
$ 40.00
Amazon
0%

0%



walmart
$ 50.00
Transit/Commute
0%

0%



north shore
$ 90.00
Other
1%

2%



Movie Theaters
$   -







Drugstores
$   -







Lyft Rides
$   -







Chase Travel
$   -







Transit/Commute
$   -







Restaurants/Dining
$   -







Other
$300.00









Is this not solved yet?

Try using the following formula:
=XLOOKUP(C2:C10,A2:A17,B2:B17)*D2:D10




Or, its better to use SUMIF() or SUMIFS() here:
=SUMIF(A2:A17,C2:C10,B2:B17)*D2:D10


And same concept for the Column G as well, just change the range:
=SUMIF(A2:A17,C2:C10,B2:B17)*F2:F10


